# Chart is not showing the data array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My D3 js Chart is not showing the data please guide me how I have to populate the data in line and area properly,

Data code - this is how I am generating my data

```
var data = [];
var currentValue = 0;
var random = d3.random.normal(0, 20);
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + i);

  if (i === 0) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 1) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 5) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 10) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 19) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else {
    currentValue = currentValue + random();
  }
  obj.startTime = currentDate;
  obj.magnitude = currentValue;
  data.push(obj);
}

console.log(data);
```

I have a code sandbox here please guide me -
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-tu-18isr

Thanks. I am new in D3js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here has nothing to do with D3, this is just the way object references work in Javascript. When you do this...

```
obj.startTime = currentDate;
obj.magnitude = currentValue;
data.push(obj);
```

... you are changing **the same object**, which is this...

```
var obj = {};
```

... and pushing it to the `data` array. Because of that, all properties are the same (the last iteration). We can easily demonstrate it. Have a look at this array, it has 10 objects:

```js
const obj = {foo:42};
const myArray = d3.range(10).map(()=>obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's change just the third object:

```
myArray[2].foo = 17;
```

However, this will change all of them:

```js
const obj = {foo:42};
const myArray = d3.range(10).map(()=>obj);
myArray[2].foo = 17;
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And that happens because they are all references to the same object.

**Solution**: the simplest solution is just pushing the whole object, a new one, at each iteration:

```
data.push({startTime : currentDate, magnitude: currentValue});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [];
var currentValue = 0;
var random = d3.random.normal(0, 20);
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + i);

  if (i === 0) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 1) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 5) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 10) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else if (i === 19) {
    currentValue = 0;
  } else {
    currentValue = currentValue + random();
  }
  data.push({
    startTime: currentDate,
    magnitude: currentValue
  });
}

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't check the data references.

Comment: I am directly passing the data in my chart, why it is not taking, 

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-tu-18isr

anything I am missing

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. I suggest you post a new question, with the relevant details.

Comment: sure, no problem.